# Convert Real packed array of pairs to Complex packed array

Tags: performance-tuning, complex, packed-arrays

I have a `Real` [packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) `arr`. It may have arbitrary depth but `Last@Dimensions[arr] == 2`.  For example,

```
arr = N@Partition[Partition[Range[24], {2}], 3]
```

I want to convert it to a `Complex` packed array of dimensions `Most@Dimensions[arr]`.

Thus `{{1., 2.}, {3., 4.}}` would be converted to `{1. + 2. I, 3. + 4. I}`.

What is the most efficient way of doing so?  The key here is memory efficiency and speed.

---

One solution is

```
toComplex[
  arr_ /; 
    Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr, Real] && 
    Last@Dimensions[arr] == 2
 ] := #1 + I #2 & @@ Transpose[arr, Append[Range[2, Depth[arr] - 1], 1]]
```

This unpacks only to level 1, and does some arithmetic.

Can we avoid any unpacking and any arithmetic?  LibraryLink's `MTensor`s, which I suspect are very similar to the internal representation of packed arrays, would store both the Complex and the corresponding Real arrays identically in memory. Converting between them is possible without any unpacking or arithmetic.  Only simple copying would be needed.  Is this also possible in Mathematica?

---

Here's a small benchmark for the posted solutions.  I am also comparing a LibraryLink-based solution.

Up to an array size limit, Carl Woll's solution is the fastest.  For very large arrays, it performs the same as user21's solution.

```
arr = RandomReal[1, {13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 2}];

r2 = toComplexU21[arr]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.026, Null} *)

r3 = toComplexLLIAM[arr]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.17, Null} *)

r4 = toComplexCW[arr]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.017, Null} *)

r5 = toComplexLibLink[arr]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0050, Null} *)

r2 == r3 == r4 == r5
(* True *)
```

Larger arrays:

```
arr = RandomReal[1, {16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 2}];

r2 = toComplexU21[arr]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.141, Null} *)

r3 = toComplexLLIAM[arr]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.78, Null} *)

r4 = toComplexCW[arr]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.141, Null} *)

r5 = toComplexLibLink[arr]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.032, Null} *)
```

---

The code:

```
c = Developer`ToPackedArray[{1, I}, Complex];
toComplexCW[arr_] := arr.c;

toComplexU21[arr_] := #[[1]] + #[[2]]*I &[
  Transpose[arr, Append[Range[2, Depth[arr] - 1], 1]]]

toComplexSz[arr_] := #1 + I #2 & @@ 
  Transpose[arr, Append[Range[2, Depth[arr] - 1], 1]]

toComplexLLIAM = 
  Compile[{{pair, _Real, 1}}, First@pair + I Last@pair, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];

(* This function has no safety checks.  Be careful about what arrays 
   you are passing to it, as it WILL crash the kernel if
   given invalid input! *)
src = "
  #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
  #include \"string.h\"

  DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){ return WolframLibraryVersion; }

  DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) { return 0; }

  DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) { return; }

  DLLEXPORT int toComplex(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){
     MTensor rt = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
     MTensor ct;
     libData->MTensor_new(MType_Complex, libData->MTensor_getRank(rt) - 1, libData->MTensor_getDimensions(rt), &ct);
     memcpy((void *) libData->MTensor_getComplexData(ct), (void *) libData->MTensor_getRealData(rt), libData->MTensor_getFlattenedLength(rt) * sizeof(double));
     MArgument_setMTensor(Res, ct);
     return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
  }
  ";

Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib = CreateLibrary[src, "toComplex"];

toComplexLibLink = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, 
   "toComplex", {{Real, _, "Constant"}}, {Complex, _}];
```

Comment: Very nice. Favorited as a reference for `LibraryLink`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) is pretty fast:

```
a = RandomReal[1, {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2}];
c = N[{1, I}];

r1 = a.c;// RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.000100, Null}

Comment: Looks like the way to go for tensors. Mine works for non-tensor objects, but then starts unpacking seemingly deeper than necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Get rid of the Apply:

```
#[[1]] + #[[2]]*I &[
 Transpose[arr, Append[Range[2, Depth[arr] - 1], 1]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
toCmplx = 
 Compile[{{pair, _Real, 1}}, First@pair + I Last@pair, 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

I believe this works with arbitrary depth, including ragged arrays, so long as the bottom dimension is `2` for all elements. Primitive test with `On["Packing"]` returned no messages.